# Cannot uninstall Azure CLI 2.0.75

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need to update Azure CLI, but I realized I had installed Azure CLI in 2019 and never update it since. I This is a Windows 10 machine. When I try to uninstall, by going to 'Apps & features' and uninstalling Microsoft Azure CLI, I see the following:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmHoM.png)

Error: Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'azure-cli-2.0.75 (1).msi' in the box below.

The challenge, however, is that I am not able to find that particular version of the msi anywhere. I would greatly appreciate if someone could kindly point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score -1):

You can uninstall the azure cli using the below command

```
Remove-Module -Name Az -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Uninstall-Module -Name Az -AllVersions
```

Using this one it will automatically uninstall in silent mode.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. OP wants to uninstall AZ CLI and you're answering about uninstalling Azure PowerShell.